# Does a minimum spanning tree necessarily provide the lowest cost path between any 2 nodes?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

If I'm given a minimum spanning tree, my understanding is that it is a structure that connects all nodes to each other through some path, and that the overall weight of the tree is smallest. However, does this necessarily imply that for any 2 nodes V1 and V2 in the MST, that the path between V1 and V2 is definitely the smallest weight?

I'm looking at a leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-costs-using-the-train-line/), and if you look at the diagram, it is showing a graph which shows the cheapest route to get to each node from the **start node**. However, you can clearly see that the cheapest route doesn't necessarily include the cheapest route **between ANY 2 nodes**

[image]

You can see that while 1+8+2+3+5 is the cheapest route from 0 to 4, it is not necessarily the cheapest route from 1 to 2.

So does this mean the MST doesn't necessarily have the cheapest route between any 2 nodes?

By the way, I am NOT looking for the answer to the leetcode problem. I am just linking it as an example of my question.

Comment: You found a counterexample, so the question is settled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MSTs usually don't contain the shortest path for any pair of nodes. The simplest example is probably just the MST of 3 nodes connected to each other all with edge weight $1$.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes perfect sense. Thanks